# lmer nested random effects with repeated measures

Tags: r, nested, lme4, mixed-models

First, here is a little bit about my experimental design.  I manipulated Winter and Summer precipitation in a way that each winter subplot was nested with in the summer plot.  I then had three replicates (blocks).  I took plant community measurements in the same area of each subplot on different dates.  I want to make sure that I am accounting for my random effects properly, where block is random, subplot is nested in plot, and the measurements are repeated.  I have tried looking up multiple responses on how to do this properly but have come up short.

At this point, I have come up with this model as being the best, but I do not think it accounts for the repeated measures aspect.

```
lmer(Percent.cover~Winter*Summer*Month*Year * species + (1|Block) + (1|Plot/Subplot), data = data)
```

Here is some mock data:

```
    Year Block Plot Subplot  Winter  Summer Month          species Percent.cover
1   2015     1    3       C     Dry     Wet   Jun       Clear.Weed            18
2   2015     1    3       A     Wet     Wet   Jun       Clear.Weed             1
3   2015     1    3       B Control     Wet   Jun       Clear.Weed            47
4   2015     1    2       C     Wet     Dry   Jun       Clear.Weed            22
5   2015     1    2       A     Dry     Dry   Jun       Clear.Weed             8
6   2015     1    2       B Control     Dry   Jun       Clear.Weed            37
7   2015     1    1       C Control Control   Jun       Clear.Weed            37
8   2015     1    1       B     Wet Control   Jun       Clear.Weed            44
9   2015     1    1       A     Dry Control   Jun       Clear.Weed            33
10  2015     3    3       A Control     Wet   Jun       Clear.Weed            16
11  2015     3    3       B     Wet     Wet   Jun       Clear.Weed            43
12  2015     3    3       C     Dry     Wet   Jun       Clear.Weed            35
13  2015     3    2       C     Wet Control   Jun       Clear.Weed            45
14  2015     3    2       A     Dry Control   Jun       Clear.Weed            35
15  2015     3    2       B Control Control   Jun       Clear.Weed            11
16  2015     3    1       C     Dry     Dry   Jun       Clear.Weed            31
17  2015     3    1       A Control     Dry   Jun       Clear.Weed             8
18  2015     3    1       B     Wet     Dry   Jun       Clear.Weed            42
19  2015     2    3       C Control Control   Jun       Clear.Weed            43
20  2015     2    3       A     Wet Control   Jun       Clear.Weed            46
21  2015     2    3       B     Dry Control   Jun       Clear.Weed            12
22  2015     2    2       C     Dry     Wet   Jun       Clear.Weed            39
23  2015     2    2       A Control     Wet   Jun       Clear.Weed            19
24  2015     2    2       B     Wet     Wet   Jun       Clear.Weed            28
25  2015     2    1       C Control     Dry   Jun       Clear.Weed            33
26  2015     2    1       A     Wet     Dry   Jun       Clear.Weed            10
27  2015     2    1       B     Dry     Dry   Jun       Clear.Weed            13
28  2015     1    3       C     Dry     Wet   Sep       Clear.Weed            42
29  2015     1    3       B Control     Wet   Sep       Clear.Weed            40
30  2015     1    3       A     Wet     Wet   Sep       Clear.Weed            26
31  2015     1    2       A     Dry     Dry   Sep       Clear.Weed            22
32  2015     1    2       B Control     Dry   Sep       Clear.Weed            31
33  2015     1    2       C     Wet     Dry   Sep       Clear.Weed            13
34  2015     1    1       A     Dry Control   Sep       Clear.Weed            15
35  2015     1    1       C Control Control   Sep       Clear.Weed            34
36  2015     1    1       B     Wet Control   Sep       Clear.Weed            26
37  2015     2    3       A Control Control   Sep       Clear.Weed            47
38  2015     2    3       B     Dry Control   Sep       Clear.Weed            21
39  2015     2    3       C     Wet Control   Sep       Clear.Weed             4
40  2015     2    2       A Control     Wet   Sep       Clear.Weed            44
41  2015     2    2       B     Wet     Wet   Sep       Clear.Weed            31
42  2015     2    2       C     Dry     Wet   Sep       Clear.Weed             9
43  2015     2    1       C Control     Dry   Sep       Clear.Weed            49
44  2015     2    1       A     Wet     Dry   Sep       Clear.Weed            45
45  2015     2    1       B     Dry     Dry   Sep       Clear.Weed            31
46  2015     3    3       B     Wet     Wet   Sep       Clear.Weed             9
47  2015     3    3       C     Dry     Wet   Sep       Clear.Weed            10
48  2015     3    3       A Control     Wet   Sep       Clear.Weed            19
49  2015     3    2       B Control Control   Sep       Clear.Weed            43
50  2015     3    2       C     Wet Control   Sep       Clear.Weed             5
51  2015     3    2       A     Dry Control   Sep       Clear.Weed             6
52  2015     3    1       C     Dry     Dry   Sep       Clear.Weed            10
53  2015     3    1       B     Wet     Dry   Sep       Clear.Weed             2
54  2015     3    1       A Control     Dry   Sep       Clear.Weed            25
55  2016     1    3       C     Dry     Wet   Jun       Clear.Weed            18
56  2016     1    3       A     Wet     Wet   Jun       Clear.Weed            48
57  2016     1    3       B Control     Wet   Jun       Clear.Weed            35
58  2016     1    2       C     Wet     Dry   Jun       Clear.Weed             1
59  2016     1    2       A     Dry     Dry   Jun       Clear.Weed            10
60  2016     1    2       B Control     Dry   Jun       Clear.Weed            12
61  2016     1    1       C Control Control   Jun       Clear.Weed             8
62  2016     1    1       B     Wet Control   Jun       Clear.Weed            25
63  2016     1    1       A     Dry Control   Jun       Clear.Weed            49
64  2016     3    3       A Control     Wet   Jun       Clear.Weed            16
65  2016     3    3       B     Wet     Wet   Jun       Clear.Weed            19
66  2016     3    3       C     Dry     Wet   Jun       Clear.Weed             5
67  2016     3    2       C     Wet Control   Jun       Clear.Weed             1
68  2016     3    2       A     Dry Control   Jun       Clear.Weed            15
69  2016     3    2       B Control Control   Jun       Clear.Weed            21
70  2016     3    1       C     Dry     Dry   Jun       Clear.Weed            48
71  2016     3    1       A Control     Dry   Jun       Clear.Weed            27
72  2016     3    1       B     Wet     Dry   Jun       Clear.Weed             7
73  2016     2    3       C Control Control   Jun       Clear.Weed            29
74  2016     2    3       A     Wet Control   Jun       Clear.Weed             7
75  2016     2    3       B     Dry Control   Jun       Clear.Weed            36
76  2016     2    2       A Control     Wet   Jun       Clear.Weed             6
77  2016     2    2       C     Dry     Wet   Jun       Clear.Weed            45
78  2016     2    2       B     Wet     Wet   Jun       Clear.Weed            38
79  2016     2    1       C Control     Dry   Jun       Clear.Weed            22
80  2016     2    1       A     Wet     Dry   Jun       Clear.Weed            48
81  2016     2    1       B     Dry     Dry   Jun       Clear.Weed            46
82  2016     1    3       C     Dry     Wet   Sep       Clear.Weed            39
83  2016     1    3       A     Wet     Wet   Sep       Clear.Weed            41
84  2016     1    3       B Control     Wet   Sep       Clear.Weed            27
85  2016     1    2       C     Wet     Dry   Sep       Clear.Weed            46
86  2016     1    2       A     Dry     Dry   Sep       Clear.Weed            32
87  2016     1    2       B Control     Dry   Sep       Clear.Weed            21
88  2016     1    1       C Control Control   Sep       Clear.Weed            28
89  2016     1    1       B     Wet Control   Sep       Clear.Weed            35
90  2016     1    1       A     Dry Control   Sep       Clear.Weed            23
91  2016     3    3       A Control     Wet   Sep       Clear.Weed             8
92  2016     3    3       B     Wet     Wet   Sep       Clear.Weed            46
93  2016     3    3       C     Dry     Wet   Sep       Clear.Weed            48
94  2016     3    2       C     Wet Control   Sep       Clear.Weed            24
95  2016     3    2       A     Dry Control   Sep       Clear.Weed             4
96  2016     3    2       B Control Control   Sep       Clear.Weed            39
97  2016     3    1       C     Dry     Dry   Sep       Clear.Weed            26
98  2016     3    1       A Control     Dry   Sep       Clear.Weed            47
99  2016     3    1       B     Wet     Dry   Sep       Clear.Weed            12
100 2016     2    3       C Control Control   Sep       Clear.Weed            11
101 2016     2    3       A     Wet Control   Sep       Clear.Weed            38
102 2016     2    3       B     Dry Control   Sep       Clear.Weed            19
103 2016     2    2       C     Dry     Wet   Sep       Clear.Weed            18
104 2016     2    2       B     Wet     Wet   Sep       Clear.Weed            14
105 2016     2    1       C Control     Dry   Sep       Clear.Weed            17
106 2016     2    1       A     Wet     Dry   Sep       Clear.Weed            34
107 2016     2    1       B     Dry     Dry   Sep       Clear.Weed            15
108 2015     1    3       C     Dry     Wet   Jun Black.Snake.Root            11
109 2015     1    3       A     Wet     Wet   Jun Black.Snake.Root            29
110 2015     1    3       B Control     Wet   Jun Black.Snake.Root             0
111 2015     1    2       C     Wet     Dry   Jun Black.Snake.Root             0
112 2015     1    2       A     Dry     Dry   Jun Black.Snake.Root            16
113 2015     1    2       B Control     Dry   Jun Black.Snake.Root            41
114 2015     1    1       C Control Control   Jun Black.Snake.Root             4
115 2015     1    1       B     Wet Control   Jun Black.Snake.Root            26
116 2015     1    1       A     Dry Control   Jun Black.Snake.Root             4
117 2015     3    3       A Control     Wet   Jun Black.Snake.Root             2
118 2015     3    3       B     Wet     Wet   Jun Black.Snake.Root            30
119 2015     3    3       C     Dry     Wet   Jun Black.Snake.Root            34
120 2015     3    2       C     Wet Control   Jun Black.Snake.Root             4
121 2015     3    2       A     Dry Control   Jun Black.Snake.Root             4
122 2015     3    2       B Control Control   Jun Black.Snake.Root            45
123 2015     3    1       C     Dry     Dry   Jun Black.Snake.Root            44
124 2015     3    1       A Control     Dry   Jun Black.Snake.Root             2
125 2015     3    1       B     Wet     Dry   Jun Black.Snake.Root            34
126 2015     2    3       C Control Control   Jun Black.Snake.Root            19
127 2015     2    3       A     Wet Control   Jun Black.Snake.Root            14
128 2015     2    3       B     Dry Control   Jun Black.Snake.Root            19
129 2015     2    2       C     Dry     Wet   Jun Black.Snake.Root            37
130 2015     2    2       A Control     Wet   Jun Black.Snake.Root            42
131 2015     2    2       B     Wet     Wet   Jun Black.Snake.Root            46
132 2015     2    1       C Control     Dry   Jun Black.Snake.Root            20
133 2015     2    1       A     Wet     Dry   Jun Black.Snake.Root            24
134 2015     2    1       B     Dry     Dry   Jun Black.Snake.Root             7
135 2015     1    3       C     Dry     Wet   Sep Black.Snake.Root            19
136 2015     1    3       B Control     Wet   Sep Black.Snake.Root            24
137 2015     1    3       A     Wet     Wet   Sep Black.Snake.Root            43
138 2015     1    2       A     Dry     Dry   Sep Black.Snake.Root            36
139 2015     1    2       B Control     Dry   Sep Black.Snake.Root            21
140 2015     1    2       C     Wet     Dry   Sep Black.Snake.Root            41
141 2015     1    1       A     Dry Control   Sep Black.Snake.Root            36
142 2015     1    1       C Control Control   Sep Black.Snake.Root            16
143 2015     1    1       B     Wet Control   Sep Black.Snake.Root            49
144 2015     2    3       A Control Control   Sep Black.Snake.Root            29
145 2015     2    3       B     Dry Control   Sep Black.Snake.Root            13
146 2015     2    3       C     Wet Control   Sep Black.Snake.Root            32
147 2015     2    2       A Control     Wet   Sep Black.Snake.Root            39
148 2015     2    2       B     Wet     Wet   Sep Black.Snake.Root            23
149 2015     2    2       C     Dry     Wet   Sep Black.Snake.Root            18
150 2015     2    1       C Control     Dry   Sep Black.Snake.Root             5
151 2015     2    1       A     Wet     Dry   Sep Black.Snake.Root            46
152 2015     2    1       B     Dry     Dry   Sep Black.Snake.Root             1
153 2015     3    3       B     Wet     Wet   Sep Black.Snake.Root            19
154 2015     3    3       C     Dry     Wet   Sep Black.Snake.Root            44
155 2015     3    3       A Control     Wet   Sep Black.Snake.Root             7
156 2015     3    2       B Control Control   Sep Black.Snake.Root            12
157 2015     3    2       C     Wet Control   Sep Black.Snake.Root            19
158 2015     3    2       A     Dry Control   Sep Black.Snake.Root            31
159 2015     3    1       C     Dry     Dry   Sep Black.Snake.Root            21
160 2015     3    1       B     Wet     Dry   Sep Black.Snake.Root            33
161 2015     3    1       A Control     Dry   Sep Black.Snake.Root            30
162 2016     1    3       C     Dry     Wet   Jun Black.Snake.Root            14
163 2016     1    3       A     Wet     Wet   Jun Black.Snake.Root             0
164 2016     1    3       B Control     Wet   Jun Black.Snake.Root            33
165 2016     1    2       C     Wet     Dry   Jun Black.Snake.Root            37
166 2016     1    2       A     Dry     Dry   Jun Black.Snake.Root            15
167 2016     1    2       B Control     Dry   Jun Black.Snake.Root            29
168 2016     1    1       C Control Control   Jun Black.Snake.Root             4
169 2016     1    1       B     Wet Control   Jun Black.Snake.Root            28
170 2016     1    1       A     Dry Control   Jun Black.Snake.Root            49
171 2016     3    3       A Control     Wet   Jun Black.Snake.Root            43
172 2016     3    3       B     Wet     Wet   Jun Black.Snake.Root            19
173 2016     3    3       C     Dry     Wet   Jun Black.Snake.Root             5
174 2016     3    2       C     Wet Control   Jun Black.Snake.Root            19
175 2016     3    2       A     Dry Control   Jun Black.Snake.Root            27
176 2016     3    2       B Control Control   Jun Black.Snake.Root            18
177 2016     3    1       C     Dry     Dry   Jun Black.Snake.Root            49
178 2016     3    1       A Control     Dry   Jun Black.Snake.Root            32
179 2016     3    1       B     Wet     Dry   Jun Black.Snake.Root            41
180 2016     2    3       C Control Control   Jun Black.Snake.Root             1
181 2016     2    3       A     Wet Control   Jun Black.Snake.Root            13
182 2016     2    3       B     Dry Control   Jun Black.Snake.Root            45
183 2016     2    2       A Control     Wet   Jun Black.Snake.Root            50
184 2016     2    2       C     Dry     Wet   Jun Black.Snake.Root            26
185 2016     2    2       B     Wet     Wet   Jun Black.Snake.Root            17
186 2016     2    1       C Control     Dry   Jun Black.Snake.Root            38
187 2016     2    1       A     Wet     Dry   Jun Black.Snake.Root             2
188 2016     2    1       B     Dry     Dry   Jun Black.Snake.Root            18
189 2016     1    3       C     Dry     Wet   Sep Black.Snake.Root            31
190 2016     1    3       A     Wet     Wet   Sep Black.Snake.Root            33
191 2016     1    3       B Control     Wet   Sep Black.Snake.Root             2
192 2016     1    2       C     Wet     Dry   Sep Black.Snake.Root            29
193 2016     1    2       A     Dry     Dry   Sep Black.Snake.Root            12
194 2016     1    2       B Control     Dry   Sep Black.Snake.Root             2
195 2016     1    1       C Control Control   Sep Black.Snake.Root             7
196 2016     1    1       B     Wet Control   Sep Black.Snake.Root            14
197 2016     1    1       A     Dry Control   Sep Black.Snake.Root            44
198 2016     3    3       A Control     Wet   Sep Black.Snake.Root            12
199 2016     3    3       B     Wet     Wet   Sep Black.Snake.Root            44
200 2016     3    3       C     Dry     Wet   Sep Black.Snake.Root            46
201 2016     3    2       C     Wet Control   Sep Black.Snake.Root             9
202 2016     3    2       A     Dry Control   Sep Black.Snake.Root            48
203 2016     3    2       B Control Control   Sep Black.Snake.Root             9
204 2016     3    1       C     Dry     Dry   Sep Black.Snake.Root            20
205 2016     3    1       A Control     Dry   Sep Black.Snake.Root             7
206 2016     3    1       B     Wet     Dry   Sep Black.Snake.Root             9
207 2016     2    3       C Control Control   Sep Black.Snake.Root            37
208 2016     2    3       A     Wet Control   Sep Black.Snake.Root            16
209 2016     2    3       B     Dry Control   Sep Black.Snake.Root            16
210 2016     2    2       C     Dry     Wet   Sep Black.Snake.Root            18
211 2016     2    2       B     Wet     Wet   Sep Black.Snake.Root             2
212 2016     2    1       C Control     Dry   Sep Black.Snake.Root            13
213 2016     2    1       A     Wet     Dry   Sep Black.Snake.Root            46
214 2016     2    1       B     Dry     Dry   Sep
```

Comment: What is your question precisely? Do you know what statistical model you want to use but don't know how to specify it in R? If that's the case please describe your desired model more explicitly. If you don't know how to model this data, then you should be asking for help at [stats.se] where they can help you with statistical problems.

Comment: Can you show us a small sample of your data?

Comment: I would like the model to have the following: fixed effects (Winter * Summer * Year * Month* species) and random effects:  block, subplot nested in plot, while indicating that I used repeated measures in sampling percent cover.  I forgot species in the first model sorry.

Comment: Is `Block` nested witihn `subplot`, and are there repeated measures *within* each `Block`? Also, do you really want a 5-way interaction or should all of those `*` actually be `+`?

Comment: I guess if anything Plot and subplot could be nested in block, but block is really just the replicate, so I am not sure I need that.  Maybe it would be a good idea to post in cross validated first, and then get help with the code.